# How to get 30 days data from today's date stored in YYMMDD format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I am trying to get the data from 30 days before from today's date but I am not able to show any output.

I am storing the **status_date** like this way

I am removing 1 digit from the status_date and then **yymmdd** I am storing my actual date

yymmdd(1 digit is prefix I want to remove that and then after start my actual date yymmdd)

- 1230509
- 1230711
- 1230509
- 1231129
- 1230509
- 1230515
- 1231120
- 1230509

```
select ul.loginname,ul.last_login_time,AU.CREATED_USER_ID,AU.SITE_ID,AU.ACCOUNT_NUMBER      
from phone_tools.PT_USER_LOGIN UL
INNER JOIN ALL_CUST_SRV_CATEGORIES@PPTOOLS_DBLINK_PSTAGE.WORLD AU ON AU.CREATED_USER_ID = UL.LOGINNAME              
-- where TO_CHAR(UL.last_login_time, 'YYYYMMDD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-5, 'YYYYMMDD');
-- where AU.STATUS_DATE = 230509
-- WHERE TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(AU.STATUS_DATE,2) , 'DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-5, 'DD');
where --AU.STATUS_DATE >= TO_NUMBER(
          --  '1' 
           --  || LPAD(substr(TO_CHAR(EXTRACT (year FROM sysdate -30)),-2),2,'0') 
           -- || LPAD(TO_CHAR(EXTRACT (month FROM sysdate -30)),2,'0')
           -- || LPAD(TO_CHAR(EXTRACT (day FROM sysdate -30)),2,'0')
        --)
        -- End date
        --AND 
        AU.STATUS_DATE <= TO_NUMBER(
            '1' 
           -- || LPAD(substr(TO_CHAR(EXTRACT (year FROM sysdate -30)),-2),2,'0')
           -- || LPAD(TO_CHAR(EXTRACT (month FROM sysdate -30)),2,'0')
            || LPAD(TO_CHAR(EXTRACT (day FROM sysdate -30)),2)
        )
```

is there any mistake above query

i am trying to get multiple ways to get the 30 days data from todays date but not able to show any output

currently I am using oracle 19c enterprise edition

Comment: What's the purpose to take 30 days? It's mostly better to use `add_months`.

Answer (score 1):

Date values should be stored as `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) data type, it's a design flaw. Storing year with only two digits is even worse, did you never hear about the [Y2K-Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)?

The best solution would be to convert the number values to proper `DATE` values, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE ALL_CUST_SRV_CATEGORIES ADD (STATUS_DATE_NEW  DATE);
UPDATE ALL_CUST_SRV_CATEGORIES SET STATUS_DATE_NEW = TO_DATE(SUBSTR(STATUS_DATE, 2), 'RRMMDD');
ALTER TABLE ALL_CUST_SRV_CATEGORIES DROP COLUMN STATUS_DATE;
ALTER TABLE ALL_CUST_SRV_CATEGORIES RENAME COLUMN STATUS_DATE_NEW TO STATUS_DATE;
```

If you cannot change the data type, then you should compare `DATE` values, for example:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AU.STATUS_DATE, 2), 'RRMMDD') <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
to_date(substr(status_date,2),'RRMMDD')
```

is the expression that will convert your string into the desired date, then you subtracting 30 days:

```
to_date(substr(status_date,2),'RRMMDD') - 30
```